# Using python regex to rip certain elements from an RSS feed

Tags: python, regex, rss

I have been tasked with creating a program in python which rips data from the first article of a news [RSS feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/startups) and displays it in a different format. The program must update when a new article is posted on the RSS feed and as such can not be hard coded.

I have looked through all of the other answers on python regex here and they all suggest to use Beautiful Soup, unfortunately I am unable to use anything besides pythons RE library. The trouble I am having is with the regular expressions required to take the title, date, picture and first sentence of the first article on the page while ignoring the rest.

[Source code of RSS](http://pastebin.com/vPgccPXP)

Comment: From what I can see the headline of the article I want will always be in the third <title> tag. Is it possible to isolate that using regex alone?

Answer (score 0):

How do you execute .py files now? This question requires a bit of work and a method. Much like asking a baker, *How do you bake a cake?*

I would create .py script named perhaps, reader.py and the I would executed it like so:

```
C:\Python27\ python reader.py
```

**Basic example (reader.py):**

```
import re 

names_file = open("file_getting_read.txt", encoding="utf-8")
data = names_file.read()
names_file.close()
```

Comment: Its a stand alone .py file that has a gui containing 4 buttons. Each button is directed at a different RSS feed and each time one is pressed the program takes the first item on the RSS feed and downloads its title, date, picture and the first sentence of the article. 

The front end is not a problem, I am just struggling to isolate the contents of the first article using regex whilst ignoring the rest.

What else would you like to know?